# What does "the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable" mean in my errors?

Tags: java

This java program is supposed to solve a puzzle. I don't understand what is going wrong in my program to cause these errors. Can anyone help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression
        The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable
        WRKR cannot be resolved to a variable

        at MyClass.main(apartment puzzle.java:9)
```

```
public class MyClass {
    
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     {  
        
        boolean APART[] = new boolean [100];

      
      for (int WRKR = 1; WRKR <= 100; WRKR++)
      {
          if (WRKR == 1)
          {
              for (int A = 0; A <= 100; A++)
              {
                  APART[A] = true;
              }
              //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(APART));
          }
          
          else if (WRKR == 2)
          {
              for (int A = 1; A <= 100; A += 2)
              {
                  APART[A] = false;
              }
              //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(APART));
          }
          
          else
          {
              int start = WRKR - 1;
              for (int A = start; A <= 100; A += WRKR)
              {
                  if (APART[A] == true)
                  {
                      APART[A] = false;
                  }
                  
                  else 
                  {
                      APART[A] = true;
                  }
              }
              //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(APART));
          }
      }
      
      for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
      {
          int A = i + 1;
          
          if (APART[A] == true)
          {
              
              System.out.println("Apartment  "+ A +"  is open");
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, do you know what an assignment is? Do you know which side is the left side? Do you know what a variable is?  Why exactly do you find this statement confusing? If the question is actually "why do I get this error when, as far as I can tell, the left-hand side of the assignment is in fact a variable?" or "why doesn't the compiler recognize WRKR as a variable name?" then you should *ask that question instead*. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and https://xyproblem.info/ .

Comment: Separately: what source are you using to learn how to write Java code? What does it say about how to name your files? Also, please note that we *do not care* that you are new to Java (and you don't have to tell us; if you weren't, you wouldn't be asking this question). We care about *the question*, because this is *not a discussion forum* - but instead a place to collect questions and answers that can be searched later.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles properly. Your error message shows the file name as `apartment puzzle.java`. Every public java class needs to be in a file named after that class. Rename your file to `MyClass.java` and check it out.